# Can't POST to nested array with express js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

It's my first post here so please let me know if there's anything incomplete about my question, or if there's anything else that is missing :)

I'm trying to make a POST request to an array in my data structure called `features`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  categoryname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  items: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      },
      itemname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      features: [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
          },
          firstfeature: {
            type: String
          },
         date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    },
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      },
      secondfeature: {
        type: String
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Category = mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);
```

I don't have any issues with posting to the items array with the following code:

```
    router.post(
  '/item/:id',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateItemInput(req.body);

    // Check Validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // if any errors, send 400 with erros object
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Category.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(category => {
        const newItem = {
          itemname: req.body.itemname,
          user: req.user.id
        };

        // Add to item array
        category.items.unshift(newItem);

        // Save
        category.save().then(category => res.json(category));
      })
      .catch(err =>
        res.status(404).json({ categorynotfound: 'No category found' })
      );
  }
    );
```

But I can't figure out what I need to change here in order to add data to the `features` array:

```
    router.post(
  '/feature/:id/:item_id',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Category.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(category => {
        const newFeature = {
          firstfeature: req.body.firstfeature,
          secondfeature: req.body.secondfeature,
          user: req.user.id
        };

        // Add to item array
        category.items.features.unshift(newFeature);

        // Save
        category.save().then(category => res.json(category));
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ itemnotfound: 'Item not found' 
}));
  }
    );
```

Comment: you can do it like this, "category.items[0].features.unshift(newFeature)" assuming that "features" is in 0th index object.

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhGhewari that did help with pushing data into the array. 'firstfeature' works fine, but 'secondfeature' shows up without any input data.

`[
{
            "features": [
{
                    "_id": "5b37a660da5d382ddce0abd9",
                    "user": "5b2b6efe4c356e1368d73a3f",
                    "date": "2018-06-30T15:48:48.985Z"
},
{
                    "date": "2018-06-30T15:48:37.996Z",
                    "_id": "5b37a655da5d382ddce0abd8",
                    "firstfeature": "test data1",
                    "user": "5b2b6efe4c356e1368d73a3f"
}
]`

Comment: Please post request.body and newFeature object.

Comment: @SaurabhGhewari I posted the console.log results, along with the intended input data here: [link](https://pastebin.com/93uSzRpZ)

Comment: Anything else that is missing @SaurabhGhewari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved with the following data structure:

```
features: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      },
      price: {
        type: String
      },
      size: {
        type: String
      },
     date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ]
```

And then simply make a post request for one feature at a time.